# Calling a function in another file with it's own context

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

MyFunc1.js :

```
function MyFunc1(){
  this.client = new myClient();
  var scheduleService = new ScheduleService();
  scheduleService.updatesometing(this.funcinsideFunc1);

}

MyFunc1.prototype.funcinsideFunc1 = async function() {
  var self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    self.client.call() // error at this line Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
  }
}
```

ScheduleService.js :

```
ScheduleService.prototype.updateSomething = async function(func1){
  var result = await Promise.resolve(func1());
}
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

on the line as specified in the comment in `MyFunc1.js`

What is the correct way to pass and execute this function?

Comment: `this.client`, created via `new`, will be an *instantiation* - that is, an object, not a function. Without seeing its code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: funcinsideFunc1 is passed as a callback. `this` isn't class instance inside of it.

Comment: You're already using an arrow function which keeps the outer `this` in `funcinsideFunc1`, you don't need to use any `self` here. Your problem is with the `updatesometing(this.funcinsideFunc1);` call

Answer (score -1):

I think I solved the problem with this:

```
scheduleService.updatesometing.bind(this)();
```

And then inside ScheduleService like the following:

```
this.funcinsideFunc1()
```